# Can I make a symlink to a Netcat TCP connection?

Tags: php, netcat

I have been using netcat to connect to my server and I want to do something like this:

```
$sock=pfsockopen($i,$p,$errno,$errstr,30); 
symlink($file,$sock);
```

but it's not going well. What I want to do is to show the content of `$file` on netcat. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not with a built-in function. You'll have to copy manually:

```
while(!feof($file)) {
    fwrite($sock, fread($file, 4096));
}
```